# Creation program which calculate exponets with the use of "for" command in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop

I tried to write a program to do the exponential calculation with the use of `for` command. I wrote the code which appears in the lines below but it's not working.

```
include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int base=2;
    int exp=2;
    int result;
    for (int i=1; i<e ;i++) {
        result=base*base;
    }
    cout << result <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it?  Let us know what you're getting thats incorrect and what would be considered correct or we can't help you.  No one will just debug your code for you, but they'll certainly help you do it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Initialize `result` to `1`.
2. In each iteration, multiply `result` by `base`.
3. Make sure `result` is the running result.

```
int result = 1;
// for (int i=1; i <= exp ; i++) // This will work too.
for (int i=0; i < exp ; i++)
{
   result *= base;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never really explained what you wanted to happen or for the matter why, but hopefully this solves your problem.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

int base = 2;
int exp = 2;
int result = base*base;

for(int i = 0; i <= exp; i++) //Unsure why you use the variable exp in the condition
{
   cout << result << endl;
   base++ 
}

system("PAUSE"); //Non portable code; used just for an example

return 0;

}
```